# How to remove one of the image elemnt inside div using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i have element div with `id="akbarslide"`. There are four images inside.

```
<img src="image_suspetio/garbage.jpg" alt="garbage.jpg" width="270" height="250" />
<img src="image_suspetio/dog.jpg" alt="dog.jpg" width="270" height="250" />
<img src="image_suspetio/bar.jpg" alt="bar.jpg" width="270" height="250" />
<img src="image_suspetio/sky.jpg" alt="sky.jpg" width="270" height="250" />
```

I tried the code below, but images weren't removed.

```
$('img[src="garbage.jpg"]').remove();
```

Comment: The source isn't `garbage.jpg` it's `image_suspetio/garbage.jpg`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use exact match as the src is not `garbage.jpg` but have to use [Attribute Ends With Selector, $](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) or contains `garbage.jpg` Use `*`  for [Attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('img[src*="garbage.jpg"]').remove();
```

If you are certain that the src endwith garbage.jpg, you can use `$`

```
$('img[src$="garbage.jpg"]').remove();
```

Comment: i tried using ID,  $('img#ImgOne').remove();  it worked!

Comment: The id of element i.e ImgOne must be unique, no other element would have this so you can skip tag i.e. img so  $('#ImgOne').remove(); will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this:

```
$("img[src$='garbage.jpg']").remove();
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D9Hxk/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('img[src$="garbage.jpg"]').remove();
```

It will find the image whith the `src` ends with `garbage.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#akbarslide img[src*='image_suspetio/garbage.jpg']").remove();
```

Comment: it doesn't work after i try this code elment still 4.
` var imgalt = $('#akbarslider').find('img').map(function(){
                       return this.alt;
                   }).get();
       var hslimg=imgalt[0]
       alert(imgalt.length)`
the image still 4